# bsddb and reprepro (berkeley) database

Tags: python, database, berkeley-db, b-tree, bsddb

I'm trying to read the database files created by `reprepro`. I don't have that much experience with bdb, so I might be confused here, but it looks like the database is layered in some way.

If I simply do `btopen('path/to/packages.db', 'r')`, I get the database object with contents like:

```
In [4]: packages.items()
Out[4]: 
[('local-lenny|main|amd64', '\x00\x00\x00\x04'),
 ('local-lenny|main|i386', '\x00\x00\x00\x02'),
 ('local-lenny|main|powerpc', '\x00\x00\x00\x14'),
 ('local-lenny|main|source', '\x00\x00\x00\x06'),
 ('local-lenny|main|sparc', '\x00\x00\x00\x12')]
```

However the db4.6_dump shows:

```
VERSION=3
format=bytevalue
database=local-lenny|main|sparc
type=btree
db_pagesize=4096
HEADER=END
 <loads of data>
```

The file itself is identified as: `/var/packages/db/packages.db: Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)` by `file`.

How do I get to that contents? If I understand it correctly, I got only the names of actual databases in `keys()`. How do I get to the contents of those dbs now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer seems to be that the "nice" version of the `bsddb` interface doesn't support multi btree tables inside one file. You can open such table explicitly via bsddb.db, using:

```
env = db.DBEnv()
env.open(None, db.DB_CREATE | db.DB_INIT_MPOOL)
internal_db = db.DB(env)
internal_db.open("the filename", "the internal db name", db.DB_BTREE, db.DB_RDONLY)
```